# Error while selecting business object in eMatrix

Tags: tcl, plm

I am trying to run this mql command on ennovia ematrix plm

```
print bus  type 'Own design item'  name  'RAU1204038'  revision  *  select *;
```

but I am getting this error

```
Error: #1900068: print business object failed
Error: #1500029: No business object 'Error getting object name Own design item name' found
System Error: #1500178: business type '0' does not exist
```

Comment: Could you try using double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`, please?

Comment: yes I tried its the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noman, First you have to search that,your business object name exist in your Matrix or not.

To check business object name, use below command:

```
list businessobject [vault VAULT_NAME];
```

If your business object name is exist, then use below command:

```
print bus  'Own design item'  'RAU1204038'  *  select ;
```

Note: You must have administrator rights.